# Opacity hover effect not working correct in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, hover, opacity

I have this simple hover effect http://www.mysecretathens.gr/Sera/index.html

```
#footer ul li:hover {
opacity: 0.7;
filter: alpha(opacity=40);
 }
```

in the social media icons down in the footer, but in IE I see a blue-border all around each of the icons. How to fix that? Do you also see this?

Comment: No, I don't see it. All I see is your CSS.

Comment: You mean it displays correctly?

Comment: Add `a { border: 0 }` in your CSS to remove blue border of social media heperlinks

Comment: No we don't mean it displays correctly because we don't know which website you are refering to !

Comment: @a.litis: See my answer below.

Comment: Also which IE? All of them or?

Comment: check your answers and mark your question as solved, if you are done with it.

Comment: IE 9, here is the link: http://www.mysecretathens.gr/Sera/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't see it, but I suppose they are `<a>` anchor tags. So for IE you would have to add `border:0px;` for the anchor tags which are your social media icons.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a link around an image IE automatically puts a border around it.

To remove blue border Add `a { border: 0 }` in your CSS

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
```

Edit: add it before `filter: alpha(opacity=40);`

Comment: doesn't work: I put it here, still blue social icons

http://www.mysecretathens.gr/Sera/releases.html

Answer (score 0):

if you have an link (anchor), it is the standard of internet explorer. in this case you have to reset the border with:

```
a { 
  border :none;
}
```

or

```
a { 
  border :0px;
}
```

and for the next time, i recommend you [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) where you can put easily your code to run and debug it on the site for questions here.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the link, check out here:  http://www.mysecretathens.gr/Sera/test.html

Comment: put the code in your css and the borders in IE should be gone. if this solve your problem, mark your question as solved.